# Laravel main domain routes works for subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

When I open `test.example.com/main` I expect a 404 error because this route is not defined in subdomain routes. but main domain routes works for subdomain. So route `Route::get('/main' ...` runs and looks valid while it must not be valid.

My `routes/web.php` :

```
Route::domain('test.example.com') -> group(function () {
    Route::get('/sub', function(){
        return view('sub.index');
    });
});

Route::get('/main', function(){
    return view('main.index');
})
```

Comment: what is your problem then??

Comment: @Sohel0415 I said, I expect a 404 error but main domain routes are involved

Comment: what is the url of your main routes??

Comment: Second route in `routes/web.php` is main domain route.

Comment: how you access the main url?? i mean your full url that is valid in your way

Comment: `sub.example.com/main` is equal to `example.com/main`. but It's wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i don't have much experince with laravel, but i think the problem is that `main` route is begin set to match all domains while `/sub` route is inside the subdomain group, so i guess you have 2 options

1 - group each domain routes together :

```
<?php  

Route::domain('test.example.org')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/sub', fn() => view('sub.index'));

});

Route::domain('www.example.org')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/main', fn() => view('main.index'));

});
```

2 - create a middleware `domain` to check the host and return 404 error if the host doesn't match ( i guess the first option would be better )

```
<?php

Route::get(
  '/main', fn() => view('main.index')
)->middleware('domain');
```

Answer (score 2):

as #saif second option suggested, i also created middleware in one of my project

STEP 1:

```
php artisan make:middleware Domain
```

it'll create middleware file in `app/Http/Middlewares` with name of `Domain.php`

STEP 2:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Domain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->getHost() != config('app.domain'))
            abort(404);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

here `config('app.domain')` is my main domain name like `example.com`

STEP 3:

add middleware in Http Kernel file which is located at `app/Http/Kernel.php` 
find  `protected $routeMiddleware` array list, and add on top of the list
which will look like this

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'domain' => \App\Http\Middleware\Domain::class,
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

now you can use your middleware in `web.php` like this

```
Route::middleware(['domain'])->group(function () { 
    Route::get('/', 'PageController@home_page')->name('home');
});
```

or

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@home_page')->name('home')->middleware('domain');
```

For example, your web.php has something like this

```
Route::domain('app.'.config('app.domain'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        dd('Dashboard');
    });
});

Route::middleware(['domain'])->group(function () {
    
    Route::get('/', 'PageController@home_page')->name('home');

});
```

on `http://example.com` you will serve home page and on `http://app.example.com` you will get 404

Answer (score 0):

The right place to manage this is the route service provider.

In RouteServiceProvider you can add `->domain('example.com')` and map all the web.php routes with this, without touching the file.

Instead, a dedicated web.php file can be created for your subdomain, in routes/test/web.php for example.
Then you can also map these routes only for the subdomain concerned with `->domain('test.example.com')` and replacing the path with `->group(base_path('routes/test/web.php'))`

I answer a little late but I had to face this situation now and I found this topic :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the main route with the main domain:

```php
Route::domain('example.com') -> group(function () {
    Route::get('/main', function(){
        return view('main.index');
    });
});
```

This took me lots of hours to figure out, I almost quit a few times. There's other solutions, as people said: middleware, or RouteServiceProvider edit.